# Как в Laravel прочитать несколько параметров с одним именем?

Tags: php, laravel, api, get, request

Я пытаюсь сделать фильтрацию книг по авторам с возможностью выбрать несколько авторов в фильтре, работает это на Laravel, фронт на nuxt. Я собираюсь отправлять get запрос с параметрами в контроллер. Таблицы в базе данных связанны через поля id в таблице author и author_id в таблице books. Получается что в контроллере я должен обработать запрос с несколькими одинаковыми параметрами id.

Вот как я пытался это сделать

[image: функция обработки запроса]

Но в ответ приходит только книги от автора с последним параметром id

[image: ответ от сервера]

Я пробовал посмотреть что находиться в переменной $id. Как и ожидалось там был массив, только не из 3 элементов, а из одного, в который было записано значение последнего параметра id.

Могу ли я как то корректно обработать этот запрос с одинаковыми параметрами, если нет то как вообще это можно сделать?

Comment: На это есть ответ в [англоязычной версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php) нашего сообщества.

Comment: должно быть id=1,2,3 (смотри разные варианты - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547490/6004176). Тогда на стороне сервера получаешь массив с id и делаешь запрос не с where, а whereIn, передавая массив с id.

Comment: Я попробовал данный метод, не сработало, может ли это быть потому что я отлаживаю через postman, а не через форму?